# If statement with multiple conditions not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I have a forloop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.bucket_names.length; i++) { 
       if(this.bucket_names[i].criterium){
            bucketName = this.bucket_names[i].criterium;
        } else {
            bucketName = this.bucket_names[i];
        }


        console.log(bucketName, i, bucketName !== 'match', bucketName !== 'test');

        if (!selectedFilterDict && (bucketName !== "match" || bucketName !== "test")) {
            rawOptionData[key] = {
                terms: terms
            }
        } else if (bucketName !== "match" || bucketName !== "test"){}
}
```

Where I use an if statement to check the `bucketNames` on the strings `match, test` but this

```
if (!selectedFilterDict && (bucketName !== "match" || bucketName !== "test")) {}
```

is not working because after the `&&` the condition is always true, how can I combine these bucketNames to let this if statement work?

Comment: well if bucket name matches "match" it is not going to match "test". Logic is wrong.

Comment: Clarify what you want to test. Are you looking for the case when bucketName is neither "match" nor "test"? If so, you need an "and" not an "or" operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
if (!selectedFilterDict && !(bucketName == "match" || bucketName == "test")) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(bucketName !== "match" || bucketName !== "test")` Will always return true because `bucketName` can't be both `"match"` and `"test"` at the same time.

Let's say that `bucketName` is `"match"`, the first check `bucketName !== "match"` will return false so we go to the second check which is `bucketName !== "test"`. Since `bucketName` already is `"match"` this will return true. Same for if we declare `bucketName` to `"test"`.

If you want to check whether `bucketName` is not `"test"` nor `"match"`, change your if statement to `(bucketName !== "match" && bucketName !== "test")`

Answer (score 0):

As others have already explained, a variable can't be different to two different values at the same time, so:

```
bucketName !== "match" || bucketName !== "test"
```

Will always evaluate to `true`, because one of the two conditions is always going to be `true`.

If you want to check that `bucketName` doesn't match any of the values in a given set, you can use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const whiteListed = ['match', 'test'].includes(bucketName);

if (!selectedFilterDict && !whiteListed) {
    ...
} else if (whiteListed) {
    ...
}
```

If you want this same logic without using `includes`, you could also use:

```
if (!selectedFilterDict && bucketName !== "match" && bucketName !== "test") {
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
if (!selectedFilterDict && !(bucketName === "match" && bucketName === "test")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already came to know that `bucketName` can't be both "match" and "test" at the same time. So, define a `bucketName` array and check using **!** `includes()` for your condition.

```js
const bucketNames = ["match", "test", "exists"];
let bucketName = 'tst';
let test= !bucketNames.includes(bucketName);
console.log(test)
```

For your code-base something like below,

```
if (!selectedFilterDict && !bucket_names.includes(bucketName)) {
      rawOptionData[key] = {
      terms: terms
    }
 }
```